# XSLT2 doesn't import user functions?

Tags: import, xslt-2.0

I've just found that if `main.xsl` `xsl:import`s `lib.xsl` which defines some XSLT2 functions, those functions can't be used in `main.xsl`.

```
Error: There's no function in namespace http://foo.bar/my-library-ns
```

However, `xsl:include` does import those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **This is no reproducible**

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:local="http://localhost/">
    <xsl:import href="lib.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="local:function()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this imported module:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:local="http://localhost/"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:function name="local:function" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:sequence select="true()"/>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output<sup>*</sup>:

```
true
```

<sup>* Tested on Saxon and Altova. (My XQSharp has expired...)</sup>

Comment: @Alejandro: XQSharp have a new beta. I downloaded it a few days ago.

Comment: @Alejandro: How did you produce the footnote?

Comment: @Dimitre: It looks like he used `<sup>...</sup>` to make a fake footnote font.

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks for the tip! @Jim Garrison is right, I've used `sup` tags.

Answer (score 0):

> I've just found that if main.xsl
>   xsl:imports lib.xsl which defines some
>   XSLT2 functions, those functions can't
>   be used in main.xsl

**Of course, this isn't true**.

**Do have a look at the [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net) library**, whose templates contain functions that must be imported by the using XSLT code. **The stylesheet modules of FXSL in fact import other stylesheet modules and use their functions**.

Here is a simple example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
exclude-result-prefixes="f"
>

   <xsl:import href="../f/func-foldl.xsl"/>
   <xsl:import href="../f/func-Operators.xsl"/>

<!--
    This transformation calculates 10!

        Expected result: 3628800 or 3.6288E6 
-->
    <xsl:output  encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="f:foldl(f:mult(), 1, 1 to 10 )"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), it calculates the 10! (10 factorial) value:

```
3628800
```

All three XSLT 2.0 processors I am working with: Saxon 9, AltovaXML and XQSharp produce this same result.

**Here is a partial view at the import hierarchy of the above transformation**:

[image]

**As we can see, only less than half of all imports are shown**...  :)

Of course here we only see the imported templates, but in every imported stylesheet module, for every template there are at least two `<xsl:function>`s.

Comment: Dimitre, I am curious, what tool does that "Template Navigator" belong to?